# How to trigger just a button in a loop JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 buttons with the same class. And when i press one of them i don't want to show all the 3 forms, i want to show just the form on which button was pressed(and i can't have different classes). How can i do it?

```
 const buttonEdit = document.querySelectorAll(".buttonEdit");
 const formPost = document.querySelectorAll(".formPost");
 
 for (var i = 0; i < buttonEdit.length; i++) {
   buttonEdit[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
       for(let form of formPost ){    
         form.style.display = 'block';          
       }  
   });
 }



fetch(URL)
 .then((response) => response.json())
 .then((data) => {
   data.posts.map((post) => {
     const div = document.querySelector(".posts");
     div.innerHTML += `
   <div class="post">
   <button class="buttonEdit" data-id="${post.id}">Edit</button>
   </div>
   <form class="formPost" method="post" action="/admin/edit" >
   <label for="title">Title</label>
   <input type="text" name="title">
   <label for="content">Content</label>
   <input type="text" name="content">
   <label></label>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
   </div>
   `;
   });
 });
```

Comment: Could you include the relevant HTML as part of the question?

Comment: @Alex98 Hard to say without you providing your `Html`, but if I had to do it based on what you provided, I'd either get the button which was clicked and traverse the `DOM` in some way to find the form which correlates to the button and show it, else I'd add `ids` to each button and `form` and get the `id` of the button clicked inside the event handler and use a conditional to unhide the correct form.

Comment: i just need to make a CRUD system, and i am at the Update part. Each post has a Edit button and when a post is clicked a form needs to appear. But when the Edit button is clicked the form appears to all the posts and i dont want this=))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your HTML stands, you can first target the parent of the clicked button, then use [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) to get the specific form:

**Demo:**

```js
const buttonEdit = document.querySelectorAll(".buttonEdit");
const editPost = document.querySelectorAll(".formPost");

for (let i = 0; i < buttonEdit.length; i++) {
 buttonEdit[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';  
 });
}
```

```css
.formPost{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
   <button class="buttonEdit" data-id="${post.id}">Edit</button>
</div>
<form class="formPost" method="post" action="/admin/edit" >
  <label for="title">Title</label>
  <input type="text" name="title">
  <label for="content">Content</label>
  <input type="text" name="content">
  <label></label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div class="post">
   <button class="buttonEdit" data-id="${post.id}">Edit</button>
</div>
<form class="formPost" method="post" action="/admin/edit" >
  <label for="title">Title</label>
  <input type="text" name="title">
  <label for="content">Content</label>
  <input type="text" name="content">
  <label></label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
   
   `
```